# How could I connect my spare mSATA SSD to my laptop?

Tags: ssd, msata

So I have a laptop, a ThinkPad T500. With a couple of USB 2.0 ports, an UltraBay (DVD-RW slim drive), and an inner miniPciEx (as far as I know) connectors.

Now... I  have a spare mSATA SSD lying around, but I can't just install it in the main bay (obviously). As I'm not familiar with mSATA, I'm asking you guys.

**What is the cheapest way to connect the mSATA drive?**
(I would need the drive for development.)

(Something like an external enclosure would really work, but I have yet to seen one like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T500 doesn't support mSATA drives, so you won't be able to plug it into the internal mini-PCIe slots (like you would on more recent ThinkPads). Your best bet would probably be a mSATA-to-SATA adapter. These can be found on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=msata%20sata&_sacat=0&_odkw=msata%20usb&_osacat=0), and look like they would fit into any standard 2.5" drive enclosure, with the right screwholes and everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy USB 3.0 to mSATA SSD External enclosure to if your mSATA SSD

Answer (score 0):

I would put an eSata card into your Pci-e port. That gives you best performance. Here is an example:

[image]
2 Port SATA 6 Gbps ExpressCard eSATA Controller Card

More information on this particular example can be found on [this website](http://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/2-Port-SATA-6-Gbps-ExpressCard-eSATA-Controller-Card~ECESAT32).

Then you may be able to go with an eSata external enclosure.